# Confused and FRUSTRATED - SQL Query Join Error

Tags: join

I am trying to join two tables and keep getting an error message that states...

The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I need to know how to effectively query the two tables without re-importing the data. The import took hours to run.

Both fields have a data type of TEXT.

SELECT doc4.*, doc.*
FROM doc4 INNER JOIN
doc4 ON doc.unid = doc4.unid

unid is the field and it is a text type in both tables..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for MS-SQL, the = operator does not work directly for text, even though both fields are the same type.

The recommendation for Server 2014 at least is to replace it with one of 
varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max) data types.
(ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

Text has been deprecated, but if it's not convenient to replace it, it's still possible (though less efficient) to compare text fields by using cast.

```
SELECT doc4.something, doc.something
    FROM doc 
    INNER JOIN doc4 
    ON CAST(doc.unid AS varchar(max)) = 
       CAST(doc4.unid AS varchar(max));
```

(Or say "FROM doc4 INNER JOIN doc", whichever is the prefered order.)